# Can I pass a undefined variable parameter in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wish to change a string like function.
let my function string is like 'x**2+2*x+1'.but I want to change x by r.
And I don't want to use x as a str during this replacement.
To do this I make a method whose parameter are formula and vav i.e., variable

So, I tried This:

```
def ModifyFormula(formula,vav):
    vav=str(vav)
    san_vav='r'
    formula=formula.replace(vav,san_vav)
    return formula
ModifyFormula('x**2+2*x+1',x)
```

But I got `NameError: name 'x' is not defined`, It is pretty obvious that is a error due to a undefined in last line of the code .

How I can approach the goal to `'r**2+2*r+1'` without using x as `str` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible.

The last line will always be decoded.

Comment: I got my answers. Thanx @pepoluan